# Check validity of string, used return False too often? (CS50 plates.py)

Tags: python

Firstly, yes I'm a beginner. The code does function correctly but it looks ugly and I'm unsure if it is easily readable.

I think my issue is the fact I've used 'return False' 5 times in a single function. Could this be written better? If so, is it very bad or just a slight tweak(s)?
`

```
def is_valid(s):
    length = len(s)
    # Length between 2 and 6
    if length < 2 or length > 6:
        return False
    # False for punctuation
    if not s.isalnum():
        return False
    # First 2 char must be letters
    if not s[0:2].isalpha():
        return False
    # Numbers cannot start with 0
    # Numbers cannot be in the middle of letters
    for i in range(length):
        if s[i].isdigit():
            if s[i] == '0':
                return False
            elif not s[i:].isdigit():
                return False
            else:
                break
    return True
```

Comment: What are the constraints on your string? 2+ letters and 0-4 numbers?

Comment: @DeathIncarnate Correct. Should that be written somewhere?

Comment: See J_H's answer (i.e. yes, it definitely needs to be written somewhere). Imagine you come back to this in 5 years, do you want  to have to read the code to understand what's going on or would you like a helpful, human language description of what this is looking for?

Comment: @DeathIncarnate That makes sense. Would you write it as a docstring or comment? Something like """Checks if string argument is valid; must start with 2+ letters and end with 0-4 numbers""" ?

Comment: Docstrings are powerful, check out [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html), [sphinx docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) and even humble [help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help)

Comment: The overall approach of returning False for each failed condition is perfectly fine.

Comment: Write code that does something and you’ve documented what the code does. Write your intent and you’ve documented what it was supposed to do. Don’t expect these to be the same.

Answer (score 13):

```
def is_valid(s):
```

You're not giving us many hints, there.
What is `s`?
What kind of validity criteria?
As an engineer, why would I want to call this function?

This function is crying out for a helpful """docstring""".

Consider using a longer name: `is_valid_foo`
(I do not yet know what "foo" might be.)

Consider adding an optional type annotation: `s: str`.
May as well end with `...(s: str) -> bool:` while
you're at it, though the helpful `is_` prefix
already tells us the return type.

Just like `i` and `j` are often good choices for local
variables that are indexes, `s` can be a good choice
for a string.
But *here* `s` is part of your public API,
so the documentation burden is much higher.
The function name didn't spell it out,
so the parameter name should definitely offer
at least one word's worth of hint.

---

```
    # Length between 2 and 6
    if length < 2 or length > 6:
```

Delete the # comment, as it doesn't tell us anything
beyond what the code has already said.
We use comments to describe the "why",
and code to describe the "how".

Consider chaining the comparisons:

```
    if not(2 <= length <= 6):
```

---

> I've used 'return False' 5 times

That's not so bad.
You have slightly complex rules, and the code is clear.

Here is *one* idea to help with clarity.
Express the rules in the positive rather than the negative,
breaking out a helper function for each one,
and string them together as conjuncts:

```
def starts_with_alpha(s: str) -> bool:
    return s[:2].isalpha()

def is_valid(s: str) -> bool:
    return (is_valid_length(s)
            and s.isalnum()
            and starts_with_alpha(s)
            and is_alpha_then_number(s))
```

The idea is to make it read like an English sentence,
so there's little or no need for comments.

---

You didn't offer any requirements in English,
but they are apparent from the code.

Another approach to satisfying the requirements
would be to express them as a regex:

```
import re

valid_re = re.compile(r'^[a-z]{2,}(?P<num>([1-9]\d*)?)$')

    ...
    return (is_valid_length(s)
            and valid_re.search(s.lower()))
```

---

The code as written is clear and achieves its design goals.

I would be happy to delegate or accept maintenance tasks for it.

Before merging it down to `main`
the signature / docstring should be improved,
so maintenance engineers can immediately
see what the function is good for
without reading through all of its code.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive answer, there's a ton of helpful info to aid my learning. I will save and refer back whenever needed.

Comment: In terms of "is_valid_foo", I would argue this depends on the context that the function is found in. If it's part of a class called "foo" or a file called "foo.py" then it probably doesn't need the "_foo" since that is provided by the wider namespace and such repetition is undesirable. I would also consider using half-open intervals for this kind of comparison bad practice, half-open is used because of 0-indexing and this a comparison to a length. Otherwise, good answer +1

Answer (score 7):

**A function with several returns is not necessarily a problem**. Early
returns are often called short-circuiting and they can be effective
in keeping code readable: the intuition is to handle easy checks first before
proceeding to more difficult matters.

**When feasible, give functions more explicit names**. The current name tells
us you are validating something, but that's about it. Be more specific with
names when possible, especially at interface points (a function name is
inherently one: it's the interface between the caller and the work of the
function).

**In Python, iterating via indexes is rarely useful**. Python sequences
(including strings) are directly iterable. If you need the discrete values from
a sequence (characters in this case), iterate directly over the string. If you
also need indexes, use `enumerate()`.

**The hard part: first letters then digits**. Most of the complexity in your
current approach deals with determining whether the license plate consists of
letters then numbers. Your current code is not too difficult to follow. You can simplify the code and
help its readability in two ways:
(1) slightly rephrase the comment
to clarify that digits are optional and (2) return immediately
to emphasize that we reach our decision after seeing the first
digit.

```
def is_valid_vanity_plate(s):
    # Basic checks:
    # - length
    # - ASCII letters and digits
    # - start with 2 letters
    ok = (
        2 <= len(s) <= 6 and
        s.isalnum() and
        s[0:2].isalpha()
    )
    if not ok:
        return False

    # Digits, if any, must come at the end and cannot start with zero.
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c.isdigit():
            return c != '0' and s[i:].isdigit()
    return True
```

**The hard part: an alternative**. You could use a regular expression to
perform most of the validation: two or more letters, optionally followed by a
non-zero digit and then some other digits. I suspect that many Python
programmers would handle it this way.

```
import re

PLATE_RGX = re.compile(r'^[a-z]{2,}([1-9]\d*)?$', re.IGNORECASE)

def is_valid_vanity_plate(s):
    return bool(
        2 <= len(s) <= 6 and
        PLATE_RGX.search(s)
    )
```

**The hard part: another alternative**. A different technique is to classify
the string into sub-sequences of non-digits and digits. That can be done
directly with
[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby),
which takes any iterable and a function to perform the classifying. Once you
have those parts, the validation logic is quite simple.

```
def is_valid_vanity_plate(s):
    # Basic checks (same as above).
    ...

    # Break string apart into sub-sequences of non-digits and digits.
    parts = [
        ''.join(g)
        for _, g in groupby(s, str.isdigit)
    ]

    # Digits, if any, must be in the second part and cannot start with zero.
    n = len(parts)
    return (
        n == 1 or
        (n == 2 and parts[1][0] != '0')
    )
```

Comment: "Early returns are often called short-circuiting [...]" --> It's called a "guard clause". Short-circuit is used for boolean conditions, where you reach to a result for the entire boolean expression without having to execute all the steps in the expression.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Sure, guard clause is fine too. Short-circuiting has multiple meanings and usages – human language works that way.

Comment: I mean, you're right. You are short-circuiting the execution of the function, but that isn't it's usual usage. That's why I said "it used for". The "It's [...]" should be phrased differently. Comments at 1am aren't a good idea... The most common names are "early return" and "guard clause". Maybe you could reflect that into the answer?

Comment: I'm familiar with short-circuiting as specifically a language feature where boolean operators can terminate early if the result is apparent from calculating the left hand side of the conditional statement, leaving the right hand side unevaluated. For exiting a function early based on validation, I'm only familiar with the term "guard clause". I definitely understand what you mean, but I agree with @IsmaelMiguel that "short circuit" is a nonstandard term for a "guard clause". The wikipedia page does not mention it at all: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science).

Comment: If you have the time, I would ask that you do further research on the terminology and based on your own findings either accept or reject the feedback that "guard clause" is the better term here to potentially improve the answer.

Comment: @Blackhawk If you are familiar with only a single term for a common coding strategy, I might suggest that you widen your experience. I'm not anti-guard-clause -- it's a valid and correct term, even canonical in this context (as your wiki-research proves). That said, I've also seen/heard this technique described in different ways, including "short-circuiting" -- a perfectly reasonable and accurate synonym. That's part of the beauty of language: we can each choose to phrase things as we prefer.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'm glad to see that we are almost entirely in agreement. You agree that short-circuiting is an accurate description of the coding technique. I agree that guard clause is the most common/canonical term. If we disagree, it's only over whether my use of short-circuiting is somehow unusual (I've seen the term used this way many times ... perhaps a testament to my advanced age!). In any case, I tend to use "guard clause" in validation situations and "short circuiting" when doing the easy thing first. That's just a stylistic preference, but there is some logic behind it.

Comment: @FMc I've never seen short-circuit being used like this, but it is an accurate description. It can confuse people, because of the (currently) more used term "short-circuit evaluation" used for boolean expressions. I understand your logic, and while I personally dislike it, I respect it and what I'm saying has nothing to do with my own preferences. Personally, I would add the "guard clause" term, as it is more recognizable, in my opinion.